# conditionally add blocks in magento layout

Tags: php, xml, templates, layout, magento

Is there a way to conditionally add a block in my magento layout based on whether the current customer is part of a group or not?

or would this be something better handled in the controller?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It would be nice to use something like `customer_logged_in` and `customer_logged_out` but sadly that doesn't exist... yet.

Let's copy the same technique. To start with you'll need to make a module with this in the config:

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_layout_load_before>
            <observers>
                <customer_group_observer>
                    <class>CUSTOM_MODULE/observer</class>
                    <method>beforeLoadLayout</method>
                </customer_group_observer>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_layout_load_before>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

In the `CUSTOM_MODULE_Model_Observer` class add this method:

```
public function beforeLoadLayout($observer)
{
    $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
    $group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId);

    $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate()
       ->addHandle('customer_group_'.$group->getCode());
}
```

Now in layout files you can use the customer groups.

```
<layout>
    <customer_group_General>
        <reference name="content">
            <!-- Add some blocks -->
        </reference>
    </customer_group_General>
</layout>
```

Additionally, this method doesn't let you directly specify blocks per page but you can work around that. Here is an example that creates a new location for product pages only, on all other pages the update should have no effect and fail gracefully.

```
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="group_container" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>

    <customer_group_General>
        <reference name="group_container">
            <!-- Add some blocks -->
        </reference>
    </customer_group_General>
</layout>
```

Comment: can these handles be used when targeting a specific page? vs used for every page when a customer is part of a particular group?

Comment: I think I have an idea how to do that, please see updated answer.

Comment: Using a custom helper as the argument to an <action> would be a better solution.  It would prevent having your observer fire on every page load and instead move the logic to the specific places that it is needed.

Comment: @Lee, post your idea as another answer and perhaps people will prefer it.

Comment: @LeeSaferite I'd be very interested to see how that is done.

Answer (score 0):

The following post will provide details the functionality your require: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/83244/#t219147

Use customer_logged_in or customer_logged_out blocks in your layout files to add or remove elements, these blocks are called last.

No need to add additional extensions or code, this is built into Magento as standard.

Hope this helps, worked for me. Magento Version: 1.6+